# GPSを使って移動速度を取得したい

Tags: spresense, gps

SPRESENSEメインボードのGPS機能を使い移動速度を取得したいと思っております。
取得できるであろう変数は目星が付いているのですが、値が0のまま変動しません。
下記の取得方法で問題が無いかを見ていただけますでしょうか。

```c
  if (Gnss.waitUpdate(-1))
  {
    SpNavData NavData;
    Gnss.getNavData(&NavData);
    snprintf(StringBuffer, STRING_BUFFER_SIZE, "Sp:%.2f", NavData.velocity/60/60);
    Serial.print(StringBuffer);
  }
```

上記の `NavData.velocity` の値が `0` のままとなります。

※他のsetup等はサンプルスケッチのまま使用しています
※時刻などの情報は取得できています
※衛星も5機以上は取得できています

Comment: 位置情報自体は取得できていますか？また、"移動速度" ということは本体またはセンサを十分な距離移動しても値が変化しないということでしょうか？

Comment: 試してみましたが位置情報は取得できていないようです
時刻は正常にとれています
確かに、位置情報がとれなければ速度も取れないですよね
アンテナはメインボードのもののみなので、衛星の数が足りないということもあるかもしれません

Answer (score 1):

ある程度自己解決できましたので、報告です
みちびきも取得対象にしたところ、不安定ではありますが、取得できました
電波の受信強度が低いのかもしれません

回答いただいた方ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

veloctyの単位はm/sです
km/hではありません
[Spresense Arduino Library: SpNavData Class Reference](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/developer-tools/api-reference/api-references-arduino/classSpNavData.html#ac739576cc353658c77d65aca3313f96c)

m/s単位のデータを3600で割っているのでかなり小さな値になっていそうです

Comment: 了解しましたMに直します
ただveloctyの値自体が0になりますので、取得はできていないようです

Comment: GNSSはコールドスタートした場合位置情報が取得できるようになるまで結構時間がかかります(数分)。屋内などの場合はもっと時間がかかったり、最悪取得できるようになりません。もし屋内で試験しているようであれば屋外でテストしてみてください。

Comment: 数分待つようにして、見晴らしの良いベランダで試験しています
メインボードのアンテナの性能が悪いのかもしれませんね
他の方は問題なく取得できているのでしょうか？

Comment: もう試しているかもしれませんが、サンプルスケッチそのままで受信できますか?

Comment: サンプルスケッチでも試しています